# having issues working with movie clips inside of an array [as3]

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, actionscript

In a game I'm making, I'm trying to have sprites put on top of a hit box. The best way I could think of accomplishing this is to make two arrays; one for the hit boxes, and one for the sprites, and then have the sprites stay on top of their respective hit-box via a for loop that will be in its own script.

Problem is, is that when I try to get the MovieClips in either of the arrays to do anything, it doesn't work. If I do a trace on the X or Y location of the sprites, I get "undefined" in my terminal.  I'm going to explain this from the top down.

Here is an excerpt from my class that contains the for loop (Dasengine is my main class fyi)

```
for(var i:Number = 0; i < Dasengine.ovrcnt.length; i++){
        trace(Dasengine.ovrcnt[i].x); //returns "undefined"
                    trace(Dasengine.ovrcnt[i]); //returns "object Onmea"
Dasengine.ovrcnt[i].x = Dasengine.enemycnt[i].x;//this isn't working

            }
```

In another script when an enemy spawns, they go through this method.

```
if(ENEMY SPAWN CONDITION IS MET ){
 Dasengine.baddie = new nme_spawn.Enemya(); //ENEMY HITBOX
 Dasengine.Obaddie = new nme_overlay.Onmea(); //ENEMY's sprite

 Dasengine.enemycnt[cntup] = [Dasengine.baddie]; //Enemy's Hit box movie clip is put in array meant for holding enemy movie clips

 Dasengine.ovrcnt[cntup] = [Dasengine.Obaddie]; //Enemy sprites that go over the hit boxes are stored here
 cntup++; //this is so movie clips are put in new parts of the array

                }
```

in my main class, the movie clips are declared as follows also I have the addChild functionality in there.

```
public static var Obaddie:nme_overlay.Onmea;
//^variable for sprite
public static var baddie:nme_spawn.Enemya;
//^variable for hitbox
```

also Obaddie= Overlay baddie. Its the MovieClip that acts as what goes on top of the hitbox, this is what the player will see

badde = is simply the hitbox. This contains the "meat" of the enemy ai.

I talked about this with some friends and they thought I might need to define what 'X' is inside of the class of the object that is in the array. So I did the following

```
    package nme_overlay {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import nme_spawn.*;



    public class Onmea extends MovieClip{

        // Constants:
        // Public Properties:
        // Private Properties:
        public static var xloc:int = 0;
        // Initialization:

        public function Onmea() { 

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, overlaya);

        }

        private function overlaya(e:Event){
        xloc = 55;
        //trace(xloc);
        }


    }

}
```

and then for the looping class I did this

```
            for(var i:Number = 0; i < Dasengine.enemycnt.length; i++){
        trace(Dasengine.ovrcnt[i]);//returns "object Onmea"
        trace(Dasengine.ovrcnt[i].xloc);//still returns "undefined"


        }
```

Comment: Why would you have two separate arrays to represent the sprites seprately from their hitboxes? `Sprite`s, `MovieClip`s, and anything else in AS3 that derives from `DisplayObject` already has a `hitTestObject()` function.

Comment: the idea is that one array will hold the movieclip that will act as the hitbox. The items in this array will do the colision detection and the player will not see this movie clips.

The other array will contain the movieclips that will simply be put on top of the other hitbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your xloc variable is static--it belongs to nme_overlay, the Class, not any particular instance. If you were to do this in your code AND you had strict mode on (which I suspect you do not, because there's a lot of stuff in your code that should be giving you at least warnings), you'd get an error that would tell you exactly that:

```
for(var i:Number = 0; i < Dasengine.enemycnt.length; i++){
        trace(Dasengine.ovrcnt[i]);//returns "object Onmea"
        trace(nme_overlay(Dasengine.ovrcnt[i]).xloc);//still returns "undefined"
}
```

Comment: Gothca, I honestly didn't know about strict mode. I'll start poking around wtih that.

So what you're saying is, is that what I'm tryint to accomplish isn't possible

Comment: Not with static variables. Why are you using static variables for this?

Comment: Okay, I know this makes me a horrible person, but I figured out what the problem was in my code. For some reason my one class was able to access my Movie clips and the other one wasn't, but its insane because these two clips access the same clips. SO I copied the class that works and I'm re-doing my code and I got everything working the way I wanted to, but as to what was causing the problem I'm trying to figure it out. If I ever figure it out, I'll be sure to post it on here, but till then, i'm clueless.  Thank you so much for your help though, it really helped me through troubleshooting.

Comment: I figured it out. When I was adding the movie clip to the stage, I was adding it as part of the incorrect class. I should have been adding it under "Dasengine" and instead I was adding it under another one.  Thanks again for all your help.